# selfcreates class an array[2] is causing problems

Tags: c++, arrays, class

As seen in the code I created a class `Punkt` (which means point in German). It is an `array[2]` type to hold x and y axis data.  The code is not yet finished and correct, I just want to get it started step by step.
The lines:

```
bool contains (Punkt &p){
    Punkt ConTemp;
    *ConTemp = &p;
```

are causing problems. Compiling it with codeblocks gives me error:

> no match for operator [] (operand types arr punkt and int ).

Where lies the problem ?

```
enter code here
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;
class Punkt {
    public: int XYCoord [2]={};
    void setupCoord (int x, int y){
        XYCoord[0]=x;
        XYCoord[1]=y;
    }
};
class Rechteck {
    Punkt ReCoordLu,ReCoordRo;

    double flaeche(double x, double y){
        double xy=x*y;
        return xy;
        }
    bool contains (Punkt &p){
        Punkt ConTemp;
        *ConTemp = &p;

        if (ConTemp[0]>=&&ReCoordLu[0]&&ConTemp[1]>=&&ReCoordLu[1]&&
            ConTemp[0]<=&&ReCoordRo[0]&&ConTemp[1]<=ReCoordRo[1]){
            return true;}
        else{
            return false;}
            };
    bool contains (Rechteck &){
        if (1){
            return true;}
        else
            return false;
        }
    };

int main()
{
   /* Rechteck sharedRectangle (Rechteck a , Rechteck b){
        Rechteck c;
        return Rechteck c;
        } */

    Punkt P1,P2;
    P1.setupCoord(1,1);
    P2.setupCoord(5,5);

    cout<<"hello"<<P2.XYCoord[0];

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: While you are, of course, free to name your classes, methods and variables whatever you like, I do strongly second @Aziuth's recommendation on going English-only.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have some problems with references and pointers all together.

The line

```
    *ConTemp = &p;
```

tries to dereference a pointer and then to assign the address of a variable to it. *() is dereferencing, &() is getting the address. That makes no sense. ConTemp is not a pointer, therefore can't be dereferenced, and you don't need the address of p.

It would work to simply write

```
    ConTemp = p;
```

edit: as domdom suggested in a comment, you could simply use p instead of ConTemp in any case.

To go into more detail, to help you understand it:

bool contains(Punkt &p);, or as I would write it bool contains(const Punkt& p) const; is called on a reference of Punkt. That means, p is not a copy of some input but the same variable. If p was changed, it would be changed towards the outside. Aside from that, however, it is not treated differently than if you had contains(Punkt p). No dereferencing needed, no pointer syntax like ->.

Dereferencing is for pointers (although you should avoid using pointers), like:

```
int a = 5;
int* p_a = &a; //now p_a stores the address of a
*p_a = 6; //dereference p_a and assign a new value to it
cout << a << endl; //prints 6
```

The & here is something different than the one that you use for your reference, I guess that this confused you. You might want to reread some basic tutorials on references and pointers, but don't take this as a message that you would be bad at programming, just a beginner (at least in C++).

edit: As pointed out by domdom, you also make the mistake to try to access ConTemp with []-brackets. That makes no sense. ConTemp is a Punkt and Punkt did not define those. You would need to go either with ConTemp.XYCoord[0] et cetera or define that operator on Punkt.

Or you simply go with class Punkt{public int x,y;}. Or make Punkt another word for int[2]. I'd try to avoid public member variables, using the concept of encapsulation, and make it rather a structure, but at the beginning, one can experiment with public member variables. Would recommend that at some point in time, you post some code for review somewhere.

Comment: Also, couldn't he just work on `p` itself, instead of first making a copy? Plus, if I'm not mistaken, `ConTemp[0]` will cause further problems, won't it? Seeing that he's trying to access an object as if it was an array when he really wants to access the object's members.

Comment: @domdom I think that Punkt has the []-operator defined. Would make sense for a point, to be stored like an array, to access the different coordinates.

Comment: @domdom : Good spot on the members - missed that in my answer.

Comment: @Aziuth: He has given us the definition of `Punkt` - it doesn't have an `operator[]`.

Comment: @MartinBonner Huh, you're right. Gonna add that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you specifically ask about is because you have declared
`ConTemp` as a `Punkt` - and then you try to indirect through it with unary `*`.  The fix is just to initialize `ConTemp` with `p`.

```
bool contains (const Punkt &p){   // Better to take by const ref where possible.
    Punkt ConTemp = p;            // Initilize
```

Your test is also horribly mixed up.  You have:

```
    if (ConTemp[0]>=&&ReCoordLu[0]&&ConTemp[1]>=&&ReCoordLu[1]&&
        ConTemp[0]<=&&ReCoordRo[0]&&ConTemp[1]<=ReCoordRo[1]){
```

It should be:

```
    if (ConTemp.XYCood[0]>=ReCoordLu.XYCood[0]&&ConTemp.XYCood[1]>=ReCoordLu.XYCood[1]&&
        ConTemp.XYCood[0]<=ReCoordRo.XYCood[0]&&ConTemp.XYCood[1]<=ReCoordRo.XYCood[1]){
```

Personally though, I would rewrite as:

```
    if (ReCoordLu.XYCood[0] <= ConTemp.XYCood[0] && 
                               ConTemp.XYCood[0] <= ReCoordRo.XYCood[0] &&
        ReCoordLu.XYCood[1] <= ConTemp.XYCood[1] && 
                               ConTemp.XYCood[1] <= ReCoordRo.XYCood[1]){
```

When handling multiple comparisons, I find it much easier to read, if they are all in the same direction.

I would also rename `XYCoord` as `xy`.  It makes the code much shorter.